# Avoid alpha summation in Line that overlap itself in Carto Mobile SDK

Tags: carto-mobile

Disclaimer: I posted this question originally in gis.stackexchange. Apparently it may fit better in here according to carto support. I'll keep both questions updated, and remove one of them if the moderators tell me to.

I need to draw a big line that can overlap itself. I am using this doc:

https://carto.com/docs/carto-engine/mobile-sdk/getting-started/#add-a-line

And I need the line to have a opacity of 0.3. So far so good; I have a line that is almost transparent. The problem is that when the line overlaps itself, the alpha in the overlapping area is 0.6 (because you see the line over itself)

In this link you can find an image of the problem:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4oDw.png

Is it possible to keep the alpha consistent, even if the line cross with itself?

Comment: Already answered [at GIS Stack Exchonge](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/269219/avoid-alpha-summation-in-line-that-overlap-itself-in-carto-mobile-sdk)

Answer (score 0):

Mobile SDK latest version ([4.1.3](https://github.com/CartoDB/mobile-sdk/releases/tag/release%2Fv4.1.3)) added feature that instead of opacity of individual lines you set alpha for whole layer. This is exactly for cases like yorus.